# Sending Camera in Push Notification in APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending camera emoji in push notification. I have defined the following code for sending apns:

```
Description = "\uD83D\uDCF7 Image";
```

The use of this code is successful and i can easily watch the camera icon in the payload . See below:

[image]

I can see the camera image but when receiving the push notification, it shows:

> ?? image

Answer (score 1):

You should paste the emoji in your code, Xcode supports emoji characters. I mean, just do this:

```
description = @" Image";
```

You can find emojis here: http://emojipedia.org/camera/

Go there, and then copy and paste it into your code.

I just run a test with an APN and it works.